# hitTestObject on child of a MC

Tags: flash, hittest

I have a MC called 'playerP" and inside of it with 7 different MC. I can't seems to hit test on the children MC, it always show [object position_2]

```
private function cMove(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(MovieClip(playerP.RR), playerP.PT)
            if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(playerP.PT))
            {
                trace("hit la");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are playerP.RR and playerP.PT?

Comment: PR / PT are some MC inside playerP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly iterating through the children.

```
private function cMove(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        for (var ii : uint = 0; ii < playerP.numChildren; ++ii)
        {
            if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(playerP.getChildAt(ii)))
            {
                trace("hit la");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i'm not actually trying to hit test all of the children, but each children MC with different outcome, so can't really use loop in this situation?

Comment: Of course you can - just put several if statements inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to reference a movieclip that has 2 layers and 2 instance references.
One is called Erik, the other hit. Currently the larger Erik is working, how can I make 'hit' be the target.

```
for (var ii : uint = 0; ii < target.numChildren; ++ii) {
    if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(target.getChildAt(ii))){
        trace("hit la");
    }
}
```

This works but on Erik which is set by

```
public function Catcher(stageRef:Stage, target:Erik) : void
```

as Erik is a class object.