# Error to hitTestObject with children objects (system warning that the property and the method are not defined)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to check if there's any children object being collided on "player" object.

```
            for (var ii:uint = 0; ii < opponentNave.numChildren; ++ii) {
               if (player.hitTestObject(opponentNave.getChildAt(ii))) {
                 trace("...");
               }
            }
```

I got this method from [hitTestObject on child of a MC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703863/hittestobject-on-child-of-a-mc),  I'm trying to use it, but I given this error (my Flash Professional Cs6 is on Spanish language, then I translated with Google Tradutor):

```
Scene 1, Layer 'functions', Frame 1, Line 57 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildAt through a reference with static type Class.
----------------------
Scene 1, Layer 'functions', Frame 1, Line 56 1119: Access to undefined property numChildren possibly through a reference with static type Class.
```

Could something be missing (like a **import**)?

Comment: Seems that `opponentNave` is not the instance but the class.

Comment: Hm... I seen another method that create arrays, isn't possible do this **hitTestObject** with classes?

Comment: @HandonCloud [`hitTestObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()) is only used with a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) to see if it overlaps or intersects with the bounding box of another display object.

Comment: Would be possibly make the class detect a object over it? I really will have to search for another some method, but nothing... I think I can try do this hitTestObject with this childrens if I go to use arrays on a variable, and so, I do a loop (for) with this arrays and I create the child of it. I'd like don't this with arrays... I wanted to do this in the own class.

Comment: @HandonCloud You should create an instance of your class which should extend a DisplayObject ( MovieClip, Sprite, Shape ... ) to be able to use hitTestObject(), then you can speak about arrays ...

Comment: Hm... if I change `extends MovieClip` to `extends DisplayObject` I can get it?